# How to join two tables?, it include month also

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to join 4 tables here when I join the first three tables(ACTIVATIONS, customer,agent_dtl), I am getting 4000 rows count, but if I try to join the fourth table (postpaid_summary) I am getting more than 100k rows. why is that?

i think issues in the month TO_CHAR(TRUNC(a.packag_start_date, 'MONTH'), 'MON-YYYY'), how to get 4000 row with min(TIME_DAY_KEY)?

```
SELECT
    a.act_actdevice,
    a.act_phone_no,
    a.bi_account_id,
    a.packag_start_date,
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(a.packag_start_date, 'MONTH'), 'MON-YYYY') AS PACKAG_START_DATE_MONTHYEAR,
    a.retailer_name,
    a.retailer_type,
    a.dms_id as "DSR/BPR_ID",
    a.dsr_name as "DSR/BPR_NAME",
    a.agent_type,
    a.distributor_id,
    a.distributor_name,
    a.SALES_DISTRICT,
    a.profileid,
    s.district,
    s.province,
    c.identification_number,
    c.account_type,
    c.account_status,
    c.activation_date,
    c.permanent_disconnection_date,
    c.temporary_disconnection_date,
    c.status_change_date,
    c.credit_limit,
    c.average_monthly_bill_amount,
    c.primary_packag_start__date,
    c.package_code,
    c.sales_channel,
    c.site_id,
    c.district_name,
    c.usage_arpu,
    c.bill_to_contact_name,
    min(p.TIME_DAY_KEY) as first_consumption_date 
FROM
    ACTIVATIONS a 
    left JOIN customer c on TO_CHAR(a.act_phone_no) = c.msisdn_voice 
    left JOIN agent_dtl s ON a.dms_id = s.agent_id 
    JOIN postpaid_summary p on a.act_phone_no = p.MSISDN 
where
    a.packag_start_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('2020-05-31 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
group by
    a.act_actdevice,
    a.act_phone_no,
    a.bi_account_id,
    a.packag_start_date,
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(a.packag_start_date, 'MONTH'), 'MON-YYYY'),
    a.retailer_name,
    a.retailer_type,
    a.dms_id,
    a.dsr_name,
    a.agent_type,
    a.distributor_id,
    a.distributor_name,
    a.SALES_DISTRICT,
    a.profileid,
    s.district,
    s.province,
    c.identification_number,
    c.account_type,
    c.account_status,
    c.activation_date,
    c.permanent_disconnection_date,
    c.temporary_disconnection_date,
    c.status_change_date,
    c.credit_limit,
    c.average_monthly_bill_amount,
    c.primary_packag_start__date,
    c.package_code,
    c.sales_channel,
    c.site_id,
    c.district_name,
    c.usage_arpu,
    c.bill_to_contact_name,
    p.TIME_DAY_KEY
```

Comment: Why u r using p.TIME_DAY_KEY in Group by clause  when you are trying to get the min value of the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing TIME_DAY_KEY from the GROUP BY clause should solve this.

The point about aggregation is that have to group by all the columns in the projection **except the columns we're aggregating**. You are using the MIN() aggregation function on TIME_DAY_KEY so you don't include it in the GROUP BY clause.